# Pass array of json objects to MVC 5 Action via JQuery AJAX, and the Action Parameter has records, but no data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I've tried solutions from similar questions, but I'm not having any success.
I'm passing a jQuery object of array rows to anMVC5 controller action.
If I specify the action parameter as string, then it gets to ation, but the param is null.
If I specify the param as a List and the jquery array structure matches the List structure, I get a server 500 error.
I've tried the datatype, the content type etc as per other posts on SO, but no success.

Can someone please help.

List  structure is:

```
public class  ActionPermission2
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public int FKMenuID = 0;
    public string ActionName = "";
    public string Allowed = "";
    public int PermissionType = 0;
    public int PermissionTypeID = 0;
}
```

Action Method's attempted (one as a List of the actionPermissions  and another as a string array :

```
    public ActionResult UpdateModel2(List<ActionPermission2> menuPermissionsModel)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateModelSA(string[] menuPermissionsModel)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JS and jQuery:

```
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()
             {
                var datarow = {
                    "ID": pId,
                    "FKMenuID": mId,
                    "ActionName": actionName,
                    "Allowed": checked,
                    "PermissionType": "",
                    "PermissionTypeID": ptId
                };

                jsonObj.push(datarow);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            //url: "@Url.Action("Update")",           //string[] menuPermissionsModel
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateModel2")",     //List<ActionPermission2> menuPermissionsModel
            //url: "@Url.Action("UpdateModelSA2")",     //List<string> menuPermissionsModel

            data: JSON.stringify({ 'menuPermissionsModel': jArray }),

            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert('data: ' + data);
            },
            error: function (data)
            {
                alert("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

when directing the ajax call to the List param,..there are all the records, but they all show the default values as per the class in which it is constructed,..i.e. no data.

**Edit2: Data ex console.log.**

```js
[{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"38","ActionName":"Read","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"38","ActionName":"Create","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"38","ActionName":"Update","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"38","ActionName":"Delete","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"65","ActionName":"Read","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"65","ActionName":"Create","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"50","ActionName":"Delete","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"67","ActionName":"Read","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"67","ActionName":"Create","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"67","ActionName":"Update","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"},
{"ID":"0","FKMenuID":"67","ActionName":"Delete","Allowed":false,"PermissionType":"","PermissionTypeID":"0"}]
```

[image]

Comment: "I get a server 500 error."....so, that means the server crashed with an exception. The first thing you need to do before asking a question is find out what the exception was and where it was caused. Debug your server code and/or check event logs etc.

Comment: P.S. you're not required to send your data as JSON - if you simply do `data: jsonObj` (and remove the `contentType` option) then jQuery will encode it for you into standard querystring format and put it in the body...try it, if it's the data which is causing the crash, that might be worth trying.

Comment: I've tried quite a number of different proposed solutions some dating back 6 years, 
i have edited the original Post to show this and the results achieved, but still not getting the data from a js array to MVC action via ajax.

Comment: so you still haven't gone and looked to see what is causing the 500, then? Also please show us a sample of what's actually in the `jArray` variable, since that's the nub of the issue.

Comment: Thge 500 error.. well for most of the attempts at passing the data, it is no longer applicable. (happens if I don't use JSON.stringify) or the last of those attempts I listed. So, I doubt it's any server side code. I do breakpoint the entry to the called Action, before there is any code,..but the other methods do work, except I get all my records with null values in them.
I'll add the data via an Edit as well, now.

Comment: ok. You are passing an array of _arrays_, but you need to pass an array of _objects_. The code you'd shown originally (the .each() loop) appeared to do that, but this edited code creates an array of arrays instead.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ 'menuPermissionsModel': jArray })` is probably the closest to the correct syntax, but you need to construct `jArray` correctly to begin with.

Comment: Yep, I've been trying all sorts. How would I then create an array of objects,..would that be my original code where I do var datarow= {..} etc?

Comment: yes exactly, in JS an object literal has `{` and `}` at the start and end, and the properties within it have names, just like C# object properties. If you use an array, then it has no property names, so .NET cannot possibly know which of your values to associate with each property in the ActionPermission2 class. The names must match exactly.

Comment: ok, thanks!! but, using that and it is matched (structure,case,spelling) to my 'ActionPermission2' class. I get records in the  action, but they all have the default values of that 'ActionPermission2' class,..not the variables I populated.

Comment: again please show me exactly what data you sent

Comment: thanks, have done so now, and added an image of the action and it's list parameter

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is;

I changed my base class from what was posted to the following;

```
    public class  ActionPermission2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FKMenuID { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string Allowed { get; set; }
    public string PermissionType { get; set; }
    public int PermissionTypeID { get; set; }

    public ActionPermission2()
    {
        this.ID = 0;  
        this.FKMenuID = 0;
        this.ActionName = "";
        this.Allowed = "false";
        this.PermissionType = "";
        this.PermissionTypeID = 0;
    }
}
```

Now I get the records as before in the parameter of the action method, ..only now they show the values populated in the js array of objects.

I also changed the datatype of "Allowed" from bool to string, as that caused a 500 error  response.